# How do I send pause command via terminal or nodejs

Tags: terminal, itunes, audio

I want a send a command to pause playing media to the same effect as pressing the play pause button on my keyboard, (youtube, itunes, vlc)
In this case, I want to explicitly pause media so my macbook effectively goes silent (I know that I can mute it, but would rather pause). Ideally without using `applescript`/`xdotool` just in case the user has remapped the pause button to do something else.

Context: I am working on an application that can accept commands from Google Home/Home assistant to control my macbook